# Django-Python | Error al pasar un string que contiene numeros separados por "," a un array

Tags: python, django

En la base de datos se contiene una string de números sucesivos separados por coma:
1,4,5,7,8,13,35,57,89,92. El objetivo es pasar los números a un array, para así poder seleccionar el número que necesito. Para ello he seguido los siguientes pasos:

- -Hacer un objeto get de esa fila (id, counter, lisQuestionNumbers, modality e user)
- -Pasar el contenido de listQuestionNumbers a una variable
- -Hacer un esplit ',' y pasar a un array
- -Así después con array[0], etc podré tomar cada número.

**Pero no consigo el número, sino contiene un objeto (<TestQuestion: 1>'**

**Ejemplo:**

El objetivo es leer el número 1 de la columna listQuestionNumbers
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se hace la consulta para obtener el objeto entero, una de las columnas contiene el string mencionado arriba:

```
listQuestionFromTestCounter = TestCounter.objects.get(user=username, modality=modalidadID)
```

listQuestionFromTestCounter contiene:

```
<TestCounter: 0>
```

Si accedemos a la columna concreta que contiene la lista de números nos muestra:

```
number10QuestionList=listQuestionFromTestCounter.listQuestionsNumbers
```

number10QuestionList contiene:

```
"(<TestQuestion: 1>, ',', <TestQuestion: 2>, ',', <TestQuestion: 3>, ',', <TestQuestion: 4>, ',', <TestQuestion: 5>, ',', <TestQuestion: 6>, ',', <TestQuestion: 7>, ',', <TestQuestion: 8>, ',', <TestQuestion: 9>, ',', <TestQuestion: 10>)"
```

Pasamos a un array utilizando split:

```
array10Numbers = number10QuestionList.split(sep=',')
```

array10Numbers contiene:

```
['(<TestQuestion: 1>', " '", "'", ' <TestQuestion: 2>', " '", "'", ' <TestQuestion: 3>', " '", "'", ' <TestQuestion: 4>', " '", "'", ' <TestQuestion: 5>', " '", "'", ' <TestQuestion: 6>', " '", "'", ' <TestQuestion: 7>', " '", "'", ' <TestQuestion: 8>', " '", "'", ' <TestQuestion: 9>', " '", "'", ' <TestQuestion: 10>)']
```

Entoces si quisiera tomar el primer número del array (1 en la base de datos) sería:

```
numberNextQuestion=array10Numbers[0]
```

**pero no contiene un 1, sino un '(<TestQuestion: 1>'
¿Cómo puedo conseguir el 1?**

El código seguido queda así:

```
listQuestionFromTestCounter = TestCounter.objects.get(user=username, modality=modalidadID) #Queryset de Testcounter (Modality/User)
number10QuestionList = listQuestionFromTestCounter.listQuestionsNumbers # Tomar string
array10Numbers = number10QuestionList.split(sep=',') #Pasar string a list
numberNextQuestion = array10Numbers[0]
```

Comment: ¡Hola, ret! Te cuento que en base de datos relacionales lo más natural que puedes hacer ante estas situaciones es tener relaciones de cardinalidad N:M o 1:N entre una tabla A que referencia muchos elementos de una tabla B. Otra alternativa sería usar un field de tipo ARRAY, aunque esto es propio de PostgreSQL solamente... Pero hacerlo de la manera en que lo haces (guardando una string) es algo que, como ves, te empieza a traer complicaciones y limita tu capacidad de maniobra a través del ORM directamente.

Comment: Gracias revliscano. He visto la opción de utilizar los array que son propios de PostgreSQL. Creo que hacer algo propio y no standar, no me convence del todo. Por eso utilicé string: 1,3,5,6,9,13,25,44,67,83 (o el string de números que sea). Pero no consigo pasar a array. xD

Comment: Claro, totalmente. Yo también intentaría alejarme de esa rigidez de usar algo propio de un motor en particular. Pero entonces te recomiendo lo de crear otra tabla (`QuestionsNumbers`) y relacionarla con la tabla `TestCounter` a través de una relación N:M o 1:N, según necesites.

Comment: Aunque si aún de verdad necesitas urgente e irrevocablemente mantener lo que has hecho (lo cual no recomiendo), ¿podrías compartir cómo estás insertando los valores a la columna? Porque allí es donde está el detalle de tu problema.

Comment: La verdad es que sí necesito tenerlo así (de momento) abierto a futuras mejoras, claro. El pasar a un array lo hago con split: array10Numbers = number10QuestionList.split(sep=',')

Comment: Bueno, okay, cada situación es especial. Lo que te pido es que nos muestres lo que haces al momento de formar esa string que es la que insertas en la columna `listQuestionsNumbers`.

Comment: ok! He añadido las lineas al final del código con el que pretendo leer el string y pasar al array. Para insertar símplemente hago un CREATE: create10QuestionNumberList = TestCounter.objects.create(user_id=username,modality=modID[0],counter=0,listQuestionsNumbers='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10')

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123418/discussion-between-revliscano-and-ret).